# SQLAlchemy get output parameters from a postgresql stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, sqlalchemy, postgresql-9.2, output-parameter

I am using Postgresql9.2 and SQLAlchemy0.8 . I have a stored procedure in database which has many out parameters and i want them to use by dot notation. But so far I have failed miserably. Below is how my code looks like.

An example to show what i am doing is as follows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stored_proc_name(IN in_user_id bigint, IN in_amount bigint,
OUT pout_one bigint, OUT pout_two bigint )
      RETURNS record AS
$BODY$
begin
    select count(*) as AliasOne into pout_one from tabe_names where conditions;
    select user_name as AliasTwo into pout_two from table_name where condition;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION stored_proc_name(bigint, bigint)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

My code snippet is as following:

```
#session object from sessionmaker
result_obj = session.execute(func.stored_proc_name(user_id, amount))
print result_obj.fetechall()
#The above print statement prints following on the console.
>> [('(1,100)',)]
```

Clearly the above result fetches string. What I want is something like `result_obj.pout_one` and use it in my code.

Is there any way of achieving it. A working code snippet will be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
query = select([column('pout_one'), column('pout_two')], 
               from_obj=[func.stored_proc_name(user_id, amount)])
session.execute(query)
```

The inspiration for this is from the SQLAlchemy list where someone asked a [similar question](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sqlalchemy/rW8vTRtF0oE/discussion). This could result in the desired output (I can't test it right now).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. Have to add `Column type` as well.